# Filter out strings that cannot be converted to ints using closures in swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, filter, closures, flatmap

So if I had an array of strings and I wanted to pull out all of the integers (as `String`s), how could I do this?

For example:

```
myArray = ["1","2","3","unknown","bob"]
```

I've tried

```
myArray.filter { Int($0) }
```

But I get an error telling me I can't convert `Int?` to `Bool`

Comment: Do you want the resulting array to be the original strings that can be converted to `Int` or do you want the resulting array to contain the corresponding `Int` values of the strings that can be converted?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what output you would like for this given input?

Comment: I need strings, sorry I didn't clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it.

**Swift 3**

```
let filteredArray = myArray.filter { Int($0) != nil }
```

Comment: Note that filter is a non mutating method. myArray will not change so you need to assign the result to a new object.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, like this:

```
let myArray = ["1","2","3","unknown","bob"]
let filteredArray = myArray.filter { Int($0) != nil }
print(filteredArray) // ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Note that `filteredArray` is `[String]`. To get it as `[Int]`, you should use *map*:

```
let filteredArray = myArray.filter { (Int($0) != nil) }.map { Int($0)! }
print(filteredArray) // [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: A better approach to the second code snippet is to just use `flatMap`: `myArray.flatMap{ Int($0 }`, or even better: `myArray.flatMap(Int.init)`

Comment: @Alexander could you please explain -simply- why `myArray.flatMap(Int.init)` would be better than `myArray.flatMap{ Int($0 }`?

Comment: It's actually not possible in this case, because the initializer that takes a `String` and returns an `Int?` also has an `Int` argument that specifies the radix. This is defaulted to `10`, but it changes the type signature so that this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only keep the integers that can successfully be converted, then use `flatMap`:

```
let strings = ["1", "2", "3", "unknown", "bob"]
let numbers = strings.flatMap{ Int($0) } // => [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: This is why I posted my comment below the question. I was going to propose this if the desired result is the `Int` values. If the desired result is the original strings, then this won't work.

Comment: BTW - the syntax is all wrong. You want `let numbers = strings.flatMap { Int($0) }`.

Comment: @rmaddy Oh yeah, that initializer has a defaulted `radix` parameter that makes it impossible to use like this.

Comment: I like this answer too!